# Set a "max-width" to a background image for larger devices

Tags: css, background-image, background-size

I have set a background image to a div but I don't want it to exceed 1600px in width. For example, if it's displayed on a device that is wider than 1600px, I don't want the background image to cover the entire width. Is there a way I can achieve this?

This is what I currently have. The image covers the entire width no matter how wide the device. I need it to stop at 1600px in width.

```
div {
  background: url("img/bg.jpg") no-repeat center top #067AB4;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: You can read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries
Be careful with IE8 : http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code in your CSS file:

```
@media (min-width: 1600px) {
  div {
     background: url("img/bg.jpg") no-repeat center top #067AB4;
     background-size: 1600px 100%;
  }
}
```